# Why is this tag description repeated twice?

Tags: bug, search, user-interface, tag-search

Searching for "*answerable*" [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) questions, using this in the search bar:

> [regex] score:1 is:q answers:0 closed:no duplicate:no

results in a strange display:

[image: Screenshot of duplicated information]

I have no userstyle plugin enabled. If I search only for [foobar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foobar), the display is correct with just one description on the search result.

Is there a reason to keep this duplication?